# Testing form submit with Jest/typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I'm having a problem when I test submit form .
this form has input with name attributes
when submitting I can't acces the inputs by their names ( e.target.InputName  InputName is undefined )
this only happens when testing , in developement it works find

Comment: `InputName` is not a member of `HTMLInputElement`, it's just `name`.

Comment: What problem, specifically? Give a [mre].